# Where do I put the CONVERT statement to change DATETIME to just DATE in UPDATE Satement

Tags: t-sql, date, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update

I have a query that produces date in the `datetime` format... see below.

```
UPDATE WCV_3
SET VISIT_1= #TEMP2.[FIRST SERVICE DATE] 
FROM WCV_3
JOIN #TEMP2 ON #TEMP2.UNIVERSALMEMBERID= WCV_3.UNIVERSALMEMBERID
WHERE #TEMP2.VISIT_CNT= 1
```

returns this: `2013-01-03 00:00:00.000`

What is the correct `CONVERT` statement to use and where do I place it in this query to return the `DATE` only and not the Time part?

I want just `2013/01/03`

Comment: What type is visit_1? VARCHAR?

Comment: If `Visit_1` is a `DateTime` it will always retain the time.  You'll either need to `Cast` it as a `Date` when you pull the data, or update your column definition to be a `Date` instead of a `DateTime`.

Comment: that is correct... now how do i update the entire column to a different format? i have ALTER TABLENAME ALTER COLUMNNAME SET DATA TYPE DATE... but this returns error that "DATE is not a recognized SET statement"

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE WCV_3
SET VISIT_1= cast(#TEMP2.[FIRST SERVICE DATE] as date)
FROM WCV_3
JOIN #TEMP2 ON #TEMP2.UNIVERSALMEMBERID= WCV_3.UNIVERSALMEMBERID
WHERE #TEMP2.VISIT_CNT= 1
```

Comment: tried this but gave me this error--> Type date is not a defined system type.

Comment: If VISIT_1 is datetime if still be recording `2013-01-03 00:00:00.000` you need to cast everytime you select this column or change data type

Comment: yes that is exactly what Im getting but I dont want the time just the date part

Comment: @IJ_05 what version is SQL Server? Type DATE is in 2008 and above

Comment: @IJ_05 Are you sure your server is 2008R2 and not just your management studio? Any way, your problem will persist as values are storaged as datetime. You will need to cast everytime you select this column or change data type

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cast to change the datetime to just a date if your using sql server 2008 +
  `Select Cast(getdate() as date)`

Comment: RIGHT... but where does it go in my query.... before or after update or inside the query itself?

Comment: Ah, I see. It well if you did the following **SET VISIT_1 =cast(#TEMP2.[FIRST SERVICE DATE] as date)**
You would be setting Visit_1 = to First Service Date (without the time) But, if it is set in the design as a DateTime column, it will always return the 00:00:00, unless you format it every time you select is as a Date. Alternatively, you can see if you can change the column to just a Date column, instead of a DateTime column.

Comment: change the entire column to date insetad of datetime... is that an ALTER COLUMN statement? how would I write that?

Comment: **ALTER TABLE WCV_3 
ALTER COLUMN VISIT_1 date**
I recommend doing this in a testing environment first.

Comment: YES @will that is it but returns error "cannot find data type DATE"!

Comment: That is the exact same error I get when I run the command on a Sql server 2005. Works fine when I run it on a 2008 R2.

What matters is the edition of where the database runs on, not the client you have on your local machine. If it is 2005, it is not possible to change the data type to Date.